# how to do "leader and follower" for select?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm writing network using Select and I'm doing "leader/follower" for select.

My Concept is:

N threads are doing io events, only one(leader) blocked by select, others may wait to become leader, when select return, for example, select return 10 io events, then leader is going to do one and dispatch 9 to other threads to do. **Until all the events are done**, one of the thread will become leader to do select again, and others are wait(because not all the work are done).

I think if all the io events are not done, but one thread become leader to do select, in some case, maybe more than one thread may handle the same io event. Am I right ? Or there is other way to do "leader/follower" for select ?

Comment: Is it possible for you do just do a select protected by a mutex and then every thread is trying to do a select ? The thread actually waiting for i/o from select will be blocked by select, and the other will be blocked by the mutex. Then, when select return, the "leader" thread just pick one i/o and free the mutex. One of waiting thread will get the mutex for select, etc etc ?

Comment: Is there just one fixed "leader" thread or it can be changed?

Comment: No, I use condition_variable, other thread are wait at condition_variable, when select return, leader will package io events into io_task list, notify other thread and itself do one task. When other thread was notified, it will check the io_task list first, if that is empty , it will try to be the leader.

Comment: It seem this is a good algorithm (the io_task_list and the variable enabling a thread to become a leader should of course be mutex protected). leader : wait on select, other wait on condition_var. When select return, leader fill io_list, take one i/o for him, release leadership and wake all other thread. other thread wake, try to take i/o. If i/o, treat i/o and after, get back to step 1. If no i/o, try to obtain leadership. if yes, wait on select, if no, wait on condition_var. Seem good.

Comment: "follower" thread remove io_task from list and do work. By that time, another thread saw empty io_task list and try to be "leader". Then it do select, but the first thread didn't finish job.

Comment: If i'm understand correctly, that means that a i/o retrieved with select and currently treated by some thread will reappear if the leader do a select ?

Comment: @Tom's Yes, while the first "fllower" thread do IO, "leader" will be wakeuped and push into IO  task list the same job.

Comment: @freestyle, yes, I saw this problem, so I use a counter to save the total number of io tasks, when one thread finish the job and reduce the counter, if the counter is not 0, it will block at condition_var instead of doing select. Maybe it may case some waste, so I post the question and ask some other idea ...

Comment: oh, so can it be possible to have a condition_var for the leader that will allow to know if all follower thread are in wait state ?

Comment: @NeoLiu yes, counter can solve this problem. Another option is to have two lists. One list of tasks to perform, another, a list of tasks that performing now.

Comment: @Tom's , yes, using another counter(std::atomic<int>) to save how many thread are in wait state. When the counter is 0, leader won't notify but keep doing io tasks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what are explained in the comment, here something that should do the trick :

First, all thread begin as "follower".
Second, the "list" that retain i/o should also retain a state (like "waiting_treatement", "treatement_in_progress").

---

```
/* "global" variable */
int nbThread = ?;
int waitingThread = 0;



//  "i/o" ==> the thread have take an i/o from i/o_list

begin loop

    lock mutex : i/o_list

    if i/o
        remove i/o from i/o_list
    endif


    if i/o_list is not empty (one i/o have state "waiting_treatement")
        take i/o ("waiting_treatement" -->> "treatement_in_progress")
    else
        if waitingThread >= nbThread -1
            // take role "leader"
            sleep(1); // little workaround in order to reduce race-condition probability
            select // get new i/o
            add new i/o in i/o_list
            wake up pthread_cond new_i/o
        else
            // take role "follower"
            ++waitingThread;
        endif
    endif

    unlock mutex : i/o_list

    if i/o
        do i/o
    else
        wait pthread_cond new_i/o
        --waitingThread;
    endif

endloop
```

---

I'm not really at ease with pthread_condition and "complex" mutli-threading in general, but appart from the little potential race-condition, I don't see any problem with this algo. Of course, your thread have to be in correct state (not having a pointer to i/o job not pointing to NULL but pointing to garbage value).

If you know how I can improve this, thank you to notice me.
Is this good for you, @NeoLiu ?

Comment: sry, yesterday I was off duty and went home. It may a little different.

Comment: It may be a little different.
I use a counter to save the total number of io task. The leader will fill the tasks list and notify other to do the io task, when an io task is done, the counter will "--counter", if the counter is not 0, thread will block at condition_var(for the case, there is no more task in the task_list or keep doing other io task). when counter is 0, that means all the io tasks are done, and this thread will be the leader(this is the last io task and others are waiting at condition_var). When the last task use much time, other threads have to wait,this may be a waste

Comment: I've edited my answer to simplify futher more : we don't need to retain wich role have a thread, it's now implicit. For your comment : It's not really different : I used a "state" in order to know if there is i/o in treatement in i/o awaiting treatement. You used the i/o_list size and a counter to do the same. The "core" of the algorithm is that the last active thread that detect there is no more awiting i/o will do "select" when all i/o are done. Now, concerning your regard for the wasted time of the last i/o, there is no more than you can do [...]

Comment: [...] first possibility : You can detect if an i/o have been already taken by a previous select. In that case, you just have to do the select and add the i/o only if it's not present in the i/o_list (probably "treatement_in_progress" for my i/o_list). Second possibility : You can roughly or accuratly know how many time an i/o will take in order to be treated. In that case, you just have to sort the i/o_list, with the more consuming time i/o first. third possibility : You have no control, so ... you can do nothing about it.